# How to increase accuracy of POLL system with item adding even after start POLL?

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

**Background**: It is a website which is collection of products added by different days. Users can like/vote products.

**A feature I am implementing**: There is a feature that users can order products by like/vote.

> Product A: It has 50 likes, and it is added to the system just before
>   40 days.
>
> Product B: It has 40 likes, and it is added to the system just before
>   20 days.

If I order by just 'likes' product A will be place 1. But I need product B to be the first place because easily I can say that Product B is better than product A because it gets 40 likes just 20 days.

**My solution**: So I ordered products by average likes per day.

**The problem in my solution**: When I testing with thousands of products I understand that it is unfair for old products. There are some reasons like, there are very few traffic in old days, etc.

So what type of things can I add to make the increase accuracy of "order by likes" feature?

Comment: Start by defining what you mean by "accuracy".

Comment: @ScottHunter  I mean something like fair for all products. Not 100% fair... But at least up to some point. For a example if I get just average likes per day, it is unfair for very old products. There are some reasons like, there are very few traffic in old days, etc

Comment: This can't be answered that easy. Honestly, its all about math YOU want to apply on your system. There's no "correct formula" that will bring you what you want. Its up to you to develop the algorithm. Its like google. They also had to develop their complex algorithm for ranking search results. There wasn't a finished thing they could simply copy+paste. For you its the same. Its up to you to define "fair" and to develop the algorithm around your definitions.

Comment: This might be relevant, from when Reddit did a similar thing: https://redditblog.com/2009/10/15/reddits-new-comment-sorting-system/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a logarithmic increase of time could be an efficient solution.

You can calculate the average as `likes / log(days)`.

You can tweak the formula by changing the base of the logarithm. For example with base 10, you would have:

Product A = 50/log(40) = 0.336

Product B = 40/log(20) = 0.969

By increasing the base, you increase the likes importance in the formula. Decreasing the base, you increase the time importance in the formula, you should be able to adjust it to your needs.

EDIT: The idea behind using a logarithm, is that it is a mathematical function that increase slower and slower the more his argument become bigger. So the difference between log(10) and log(20) is much bigger than the difference between log(100) and log(110), even though the difference between 10-20 and 100-110 is the same.